# How to use crop huge batch of images in tensorflow

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow

I am trying to use below function to crop large number of images 100,000s. I am doing this operation serially, but its taking lot of time. What is the efficient way to do this?

```
   tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box
```

Below is my code:

```
    def crop_images(img_dir, list_images):
        outlist=[]
        with tf.Session() as session:
            for image1 in list_images[:5]:
               image = mpimg.imread(img_dir+image1)
               x = tf.Variable(image, name='x')
               data_t = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8)
               op = tf.image.encode_jpeg(data_t, format='rgb')
               model = tf.global_variables_initializer()
               img_name = "img/"+image1.split("_img_0")[0] + "/img_0"+image1.split("_img_0")[1]
               height = x.shape[1]
               [x1,y1,x2,y2] = img_bbox_dict[img_name]
               x = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(x, int(y1), int(x1), int(y2)-int(y1), int(x2)-int(x1))
               session.run(model)
               result = session.run(x)
               data_np = session.run(op, feed_dict={ data_t: result })
               with open(img_path+image1, 'w+') as fd:
                 fd.write(data_np)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it with tensorflow ?

Comment: You would almost certainly be faster using **GNU Parallel** and `libvips` but you have not indicated what platform you are on, nor what type of images you have, nor how they need cropping...

Comment: Maybe use queues and workers ...

Comment: Please follow up comments on your post else you make people think you have abandoned the question and they won't bother answering you.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a simplified version of one of the examples from Tensorflow's Programmer's guide on reading data which can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/programmers_guide/reading_data#batching). Basically, it uses Reader and Filename Queues to batch together image data using a specified number of threads. These threads are coordinated using what is called a thread Coordinator.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import glob

images_path = "./"  #RELATIVE glob pathname of current directory
images_extension = "*.png"

# Save the list of files matching pattern, so it is only computed once.
filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once(glob.glob(images_path+images_extension))
batch_size = len(glob.glob1(images_path,images_extension))

num_epochs=1
standard_size = [500, 500]
num_channels = 3

min_after_dequeue = 10
num_preprocess_threads = 3
seed = 14131

"""
IMPORTANT: Cropping params. These are arbitrary values used only for this example. 
You will have to change them according to your requirements.
"""
crop_size=[200,200]
boxes = [1,1,460,460]


"""
'WholeFileReader' is a Reader who's 'read' method outputs the next 
key-value pair of the filename and the contents of the file (the image) from 
the Queue, both of which are string scalar Tensors.

Note that the The QueueRunner works in a thread separate from the 
Reader that pulls filenames from the queue, so the shuffling and enqueuing 
process does not block the reader.

'resize_images' is used so that all images are resized to the same 
size (Aspect ratios may change, so in that case use resize_image_with_crop_or_pad)

'set_shape' is used because the height and width dimensions of 'image' are 
data dependent and cannot be computed without executing this operation. Without 
this Op, the 'image' Tensor's shape will have None as Dimensions.
"""
def read_my_file_format(filename_queue, standard_size, num_channels):
    image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    _, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)

    if "jpg" in images_extension:
        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)
    elif "png" in images_extension:
        image = tf.image.decode_png(image_file)

    image = tf.image.resize_images(image, standard_size)
    image.set_shape(standard_size+[num_channels])
    print "Successfully read file!"
    return image



"""
'string_input_producer' Enters matched filenames into a 'QueueRunner' FIFO Queue.

'shuffle_batch' creates batches by randomly shuffling tensors. The 'capacity' 
argument controls the how long the prefetching is allowed to grow the queues.
'min_after_dequeue' defines how big a buffer we will randomly 
sample from -- bigger means better shuffling but slower startup & more memory used.
'capacity' must be larger than 'min_after_dequeue' and the amount larger 
determines the maximum we will prefetch. 
Recommendation: min_after_dequeue + (num_threads + a small safety margin) * batch_size
"""
def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs, standard_size, num_channels, min_after_dequeue, num_preprocess_threads, seed):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)
    example = read_my_file_format(filename_queue, standard_size, num_channels)
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
    example_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([example], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity, min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue, num_threads=num_preprocess_threads, seed=seed, enqueue_many=False)
    print "Batching Successful!"
    return example_batch


"""
Any transformation on the image batch goes here. Refer the documentation 
for the details of how the cropping is done using this function.
"""
def crop_batch(image_batch, batch_size, b_boxes, crop_size):
    cropped_images = tf.image.crop_and_resize(image_batch, boxes=[b_boxes for _ in xrange(batch_size)], box_ind=[i for i in xrange(batch_size)], crop_size=crop_size)
    print "Cropping Successful!"
    return cropped_images


example_batch = input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs, standard_size, num_channels, min_after_dequeue, num_preprocess_threads, seed)
cropped_images = crop_batch(example_batch, batch_size, boxes, crop_size)



"""
if 'num_epochs' is not `None`, the 'string_input_producer' function creates local 
counter `epochs`. Use `local_variables_initializer()` to initialize local variables.

'Coordinator' class implements a simple mechanism to coordinate the termination 
of a set of threads. Any of the threads can call `coord.request_stop()` to ask for all 
the threads to stop. To cooperate with the requests, each thread must check for 
`coord.should_stop()` on a regular basis. 
`coord.should_stop()` returns True` as soon as `coord.request_stop()` has been called.
A thread can report an exception to the coordinator as part of the `should_stop()` 
call. The exception will be re-raised from the `coord.join()` call.

After a thread has called `coord.request_stop()` the other threads have a 
fixed time to stop, this is called the 'stop grace period' and defaults to 2 minutes. 
If any of the threads is still alive after the grace period expires `coord.join()` 
raises a RuntimeError reporting the laggards.


IMPORTANT: 'start_queue_runners' starts threads for all queue runners collected in 
the graph, & returns the list of all threads. This must be executed BEFORE running 
any other training/inference/operation steps, or it will hang forever.
"""
with tf.Session() as sess:
    _, _ = sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()])
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    try:
        while not coord.should_stop():
            # Run training steps or whatever
            cropped_images1 = sess.run(cropped_images)
            print cropped_images1.shape

    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print('Load and Process done -- epoch limit reached')
    finally:
        # When done, ask the threads to stop.
        coord.request_stop()

coord.join(threads)
sess.close()
```